# browsers not working properly in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 and none of the browsers are working properly. Many of the webpages either take long time to load or will be rendered as just plain HTML text. Also when I tried to install 'google-chrome' it showed me this error

> "The package is of bad quality - google chrome"

Please help.

Comment: Your problem might be with your internet connection - does everything else function properly?  Does everything work fine under Windows or another computer connected to the same connection?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has to do anything with Ubuntu. It seems more like a problem of the browser or the internet connection.

Anyway, to install Google Chrome, you should head to http://google.com/chrome and download the 32/64 bit .deb installer.

Once downloaded, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), go to the directory where the file is downloaded and run `dpkg -i file_name.deb`.

If you get an error, while installing try running this command first:

```
sudo apt-get install libnspr4-0d libnss3-1d libxss1 libcurl3
```

and then reinstall Chrome.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, It happens in all browsers I have installed on my ubuntu 12.10 (chrome and firefox), both browser works fine with some websites, and for some they keep loading.
for example, when I try to open https://login.skype.com/account/signup-form, both browser takes long time to load the page, and then shows design broken page...
But other websites open instantly, and other internet applications work fine, so nothing wrong with particular browser or internet connection.

Comment: please share here asap if you have any idea, or we need to move to other operating system, we are not able to access most important websites... :(

Comment: does it work properly in Windows? If yes, try doing it on a Live USB.

Comment: Yes, It was working properly in windows, I have installed windows now again, and It is working fine. If this issue can be narrowed down and fixed, Then I strongly prefer to use Ubuntu. I really love it. And second thing hurt me was bluetooth was not working, when I start bluetooth device and try to connect/transfer file, it don't show anything, no message/error. I don't know why. I can provide you hardware details if someone else faced the same, and if you want to go in deep to solve this problems.. Thanks...and thanks to green7 for response :)

Comment: and what about Live USB? Do the browsers work properly there?

Comment: I have not tested it yet, i will try that too, and will reply

Comment: any replies now?

Comment: I too have this issue, Firefox loads websites very slowly and chrome use to work fine but now it also having slower load time. My Internet speed is very fast and the fact that Firefox gives even slower speed.

I had to move to chrome because of this. Is there something that can help this fixed?